# Where to initialize code that needs a valid Canvas?

Tags: delphi

I have a control derived from TStringGrid.
During creation I want to access the Cancas to do some one time initializing.
I can't do it in Create because the Canvas is not ready yet. I also can't do it in CreateWnd because CreateWnd it is called multiple times.

There are some cheap tricks (use a Boolean variable) to initialize that var only once but I would like to know how to do it the 'nice way'.
So, since Create and CreateWnd is not a good place, where during the creation of a control can I initialize the var ONLY once.

Comment: Cannot you just check before the first time you use it?

Comment: Generally you don't want to do it only once, the control's font can change for instance.

Comment: @Sertac, good point! Isn't the `CM_FONTCHANGED` message handler the right place anyway ? Isn't that message sent at control initialization as well ?

Comment: @TLama - Well, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be called when painting.

Comment: @Sertac, premature optimization, maybe ?

Comment: @TLama - Yes, painting is expensive, that wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Sorry for confusion with the Canvas.TextHeight. The general question is where I can initialize code that needs a valid handle and do it only ONCE.

Comment: If you need to do something with a valid handle, then you *don't* just want to do it once. The point of the `TCanvas` abstraction is that *the underlying DC handle can change*.

Comment: You can only do it once if you want to get the wrong answer. If you want to get the wrong answer, why both calling TextHeight at all? Just make up a value. Pick 42 or something.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you should not cache this value. Calculate the value on demand, when you need it.

Caching is something that you should avoid doing. The problem with caching is that you have to make sure that you never work with a stale value. You need to respond to anything that might result in a change in the value and update your cached value.

It's easy to get that updating logic wrong. Even if you get it right, you've just added a whole load of complexity to your code. And you always want to avoid that if possible. In the case of a physical font metric, they are cheap to obtain in comparison with what you use them for. Invariably you will be using the font metric as part of your painting code. And surely that is many orders of magnitude more expensive than obtaining a font metric.

So, you can make all your problems go away by the very simple expedient of not caching, and obtaining the font metric as and when you need it. By all means wrap it up in a property with a getter method to make the code as clean as possible.